# EF: The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable

Tags: sql-server, string, linq-to-sql

I get this error because I have a SQL Server table with a column of type "text".

```
The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable
```

Any way to resolve this without changing the data type?

Here is my linq statement (it's long):

```
                var query = (from s in db.tblSuppliers
                             join p in
                                 (
                                    from p1 in db.tblSupplierPricingSchemes
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        p1.SupplierID,
                                        p1.PSLangPairID,
                                        p1.CustomerID,
                                        p1.PSLanguageStatus,
                                        p1.PSPriceBasis,
                                        p1.PSMinFlatCharge,
                                        p1.PSTrxPrf,
                                        p1.PSNoMatch,
                                        p1.PSFuzzy,
                                        p1.PS100Match_Rep,
                                        p1.PSTrxOnly,
                                        p1.PSPrfOnly,
                                        p1.PSLinquisticHourlyRate,
                                        p1.PSDTPType,
                                        p1.PSDTPRate,
                                        p1.PS_FZ50,
                                        p1.PS_FZ75,
                                        p1.PS_FZ85,
                                        p1.PS_FZ95,
                                        p1.PS_FZ100,
                                        p1.PS_FZREPS,
                                        p1.PSPerfectMatch
                                    }
                                 ) on s.SupplierID equals p.SupplierID
                             join p2 in
                                 (
                                        from p in db.tblSupplierPricingSchemes
                                        where custID.Contains(p.CustomerID) && p.PSLangPairID == languagePairID
                                        group p by new { p.SupplierID, p.PSLangPairID, p.PSPriceBasis } into g
                                        let CustomerID = g.Max(uh => uh.CustomerID)
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            g.Key.SupplierID,
                                            g.Key.PSLangPairID,
                                            g.Key.PSPriceBasis,
                                            CustomerID
                                        }
                                 ) on p.SupplierID equals p2.SupplierID
                             join b in db.tblPricingBasis on p.PSPriceBasis equals b.PricingBasisID
                             join ss in db.tblSupplierStatus on p.PSLanguageStatus equals ss.SupplierStatusID into g1
                             from ss in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                             join l in db.tblLangPairs on p.PSLangPairID equals l.ProductID
                             where l.ProductID == languagePairID
                                && p.PSLangPairID == p2.PSLangPairID
                                && p.CustomerID == p2.CustomerID
                                && p.PSPriceBasis == p2.PSPriceBasis
                             select new PreferredSupplier
                             {
                                 SupplierID = s.SupplierID,
                                 //SupplierName = s.CompanyName != null ? s.CompanyName + "-" + s.SupplierFirstName + " " + s.SupplierLastName
                                 //                                     : s.SupplierFirstName + " " + s.SupplierLastName,

                                 SupplierName = s.CompanyName != null
                                            ? s.SupplierFirstName != null || s.SupplierLastName != null
                                                    ? s.CompanyName + "-" + s.SupplierFirstName + " " + s.SupplierLastName
                                                    : s.CompanyName
                                            : s.SupplierFirstName + " " + s.SupplierLastName,

                                 CompanyName = s.CompanyName,
                                 SupplierFirstName = s.SupplierFirstName,
                                 SupplierLastName = s.SupplierLastName,

                                 SupplierStatus = p.CustomerID == customerID ? "Team Member" : ss.SupplierStatus,
                                 Email = (string)s.SupplierEmails,

                                 Rate = (s.VolumeDiscountType == 1 ? // Percentage
                                     //if the volume discount is as percentage then get the rate and multiple it by 1 - the discount percentage
                                        ((words > s.VolumeDiscountAmount && (task == "TM No Match" || task == "Translation/Proofreading")) ? 1 - s.VolumeDiscountValue : 1) *
                                                    (
                                                        rateField == "PSTrxPrf" ? p.PSTrxPrf :
                                                        rateField == "PSNoMatch" ? p.PSNoMatch :
                                                        rateField == "PSFuzzy" ? p.PSFuzzy :
                                                        rateField == "PS100Match_Rep" ? p.PS100Match_Rep :
                                                        rateField == "PSLinquisticHourlyRate" ? p.PSLinquisticHourlyRate :
                                                        rateField == "PSDTPRate" ? p.PSDTPRate :
                                                        rateField == "PS_FZ50" ? p.PS_FZ50 :
                                                        rateField == "PS_FZ75" ? p.PS_FZ75 :
                                                        rateField == "PS_FZ85" ? p.PS_FZ85 :
                                                        rateField == "PS_FZ95" ? p.PS_FZ95 :
                                                        rateField == "PS_FZ100" ? p.PS_FZ100 :
                                                        rateField == "PS_FZREPS" ? p.PS_FZREPS :
                                                        rateField == "PSPerfectMatch" ? p.PSPerfectMatch : null
                                                    ) :
                                     // Discount in Amount
                                     // Take the Rate and substract the amount to discount
                                                   (
                                                        rateField == "PSTrxPrf" ? p.PSTrxPrf :
                                                        rateField == "PSNoMatch" ? p.PSNoMatch :
                                                        rateField == "PSFuzzy" ? p.PSFuzzy :
                                                        rateField == "PS100Match_Rep" ? p.PS100Match_Rep :
                                                        rateField == "PSLinquisticHourlyRate" ? p.PSLinquisticHourlyRate :
                                                        rateField == "PSDTPRate" ? p.PSDTPRate :
                                                        rateField == "PS_FZ50" ? p.PS_FZ50 :
                                                        rateField == "PS_FZ75" ? p.PS_FZ75 :
                                                        rateField == "PS_FZ85" ? p.PS_FZ85 :
                                                        rateField == "PS_FZ95" ? p.PS_FZ95 :
                                                        rateField == "PS_FZ100" ? p.PS_FZ100 :
                                                        rateField == "PS_FZREPS" ? p.PS_FZREPS :
                                                        rateField == "PSPerfectMatch" ? p.PSPerfectMatch : null
                                                     ) - (s.VolumeDiscountValue == null ? 0 : s.VolumeDiscountValue)),
                                 //PSMinFlatCharge = p.PSMinFlatCharge,
                                MinimumFee = p.PSMinFlatCharge,

                                 //Basis = b.PricingBasisDesc,
                                 Basis = task == "DTP" || task == "DTP Edit" ? p.PSDTPType : b.PricingBasisDesc,

                                 StatusOrder = p.CustomerID == customerID ? 0 : p.PSLanguageStatus == null ? 1000 : p.PSLanguageStatus
                             }).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Simple answer is "don't use text".

It was deprecated for [varchar(max)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178158.aspx) years ago when SQL Server 2005 was released.

The code you have is issuing SELECT DISTINCT. 
You need to fix the model/tables so it isn't `text` datatype

Comment: +1 Good answer gbn. Are you really storing over 8000 characters here Steve? If so, use varchar(max). As gbn has said, text has been deprecated for awhile now. Furthermore, I'd question why this much logic belongs in the application layer. I'd recommend pushing every ounce of it into a stored procedure. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do this without modifying the schema, like casting something in the Linq statement.

Comment: @SteveB: you will have to do this eventually. Fixing it in LINQ is not the correct way.

Comment: i just altered my column from ntext to nvarchar(max) , now i can fetch the details using linq

Comment: This same error also occurs for CLR types like geography, geometry and hierarchyid which are most definitely NOT deprecated and the solution to the problem is not to work around by casting everything to varchar(MAX)/nvarchar(MAX).

Comment: @ChrisDisley The question was *specfically* about `text`, not any of geography, geometry and hierarchyid data types. I answered regarding this deprecated data type `text`...

Answer (score 22):

Cast your TEXT data types to VARCHAR(MAX), like this ...

```
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(emailaddr AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS emailaddr FROM myTable
```

Or use VARCHAR(8000), as it's effectively the same.

Answer (score 21):

Cast any text data types to `varchar(max)`.

If you can point out the actual column from your code I'll show you what the `select` would look like.

Comment: +1 - if your problem is in a stored procedure and you can't change the column data type

Comment: Thank you, this worked well since our database was wanting us to drop and re-load the original table!