# Fill combobox without duplicates from stored procedure

Tags: c#, database, stored-procedures, combobox, duplicates

I'm trying to fill a combobox with data I get from a stored procedure. But it shows duplicates of everything.

Anyway to leave out these doubles and just show everything once?

stored procedure:

```
SELECT *
FROM Personeel
LEFT JOIN Afdeling ON Afdeling.AfdelingID = Personeel.AfdelingID
```

Changed stored procedure:

```
SELECT distinct *
FROM Personeel
LEFT JOIN Afdeling ON Afdeling.AfdelingID = Personeel.AfdelingID
```

See image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1YaW.png

Data when stored procedure is executed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNBvY.png

I can make a new stored procedure. But then why would I if I can use one I already have?

Help? Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't really provide enough information for someone to help you with specifics (e.g. no table schema information and unknown object types for how the data is stored on the C# side) and you didn't share what you've already tried to cut out the duplicates.  How do you think it should be done?

Comment: How are you **binding** that data to your combobox? Possibly multiple times, I'd say - I don't think this is really a SQL or stored procedure problem - much more likely a logic problem in your application code

Comment: Code main window: 
cboAfdeling.ItemsSource = MedewerkerDAL.GetUsers().DefaultView;

Code Class MedewerkerDAL:
public static DataTable GetUsers(){
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_GetUsers", ConnectionDAL.GetConnection());
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
@marc_s

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear it of all items before populating it again. You've added all items once, and then again; each item has been added twice.

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion without seeing any of his code?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM Personeel

Distinct will return only one

Comment: This gives an error: Msg 421, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_GetUsers, Line 13
The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

Comment: It looks like he wants a distinct list of names.  `DISTINCT *` won't return a distinct list of names if for example one of the columns contains a unique id or some other meta data.

Comment: @user2287508 You might enjoy actually researching some of these issues yourself:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056339/ef-the-text-data-type-cannot-be-selected-as-distinct-because-it-is-not-comparab

Comment: @JustinHelgerson djee thanks, way to go with the sarcasm, now the distinct works, still doesn't removes the duplicates.